# i want save leaflet MAP with Layers in Jpeg Format with Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i use leaflet in my project and load data over map 
 now i want save map and data in Jpeg Format 
How can I save this map with  javascript 
can i use command like

```
map.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) plugin. Install it and then use the code like this:

```
leafletImage(map, function(err, canvas) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL());
    a.setAttribute('download', 'image');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
});
```

Comment: i get this error Uncaught TypeError: layer._adjustTilePoint is not a function

Comment: i solve problem but now only save map and didn't save other layer

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for this: [Leaflet.print](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.print), [leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image), [leaflet-easyPrint](https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint) and [leaflet.browser.print](https://github.com/Igor-Vladyka/leaflet.browser.print).

You can fins this list in the [Print/export](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport) section of leaflet plugins.